# Is this code protected for SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, code-injection, protected

is this safe enough? Or should it be improved? Is this code protected for SQL injection? (PHP)

```
if (isset($_POST['mailSet'])) {
$asd=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'TypeM', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$zxc=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mailFor', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
global $wpdb;

try {
    $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE mail_sttng set setting_val=%d
    WHERE setting=1
    ", $asd));
    $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE mail_sttng set setting_val=%d
    WHERE setting=2
    ", $zxc));


bla bla...
```

Comment: Missing tag? `php` perhaps?

Comment: I didn't include all of the code. Yes, PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it for granted that `$wpdb` is [from the WordPress project](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/).

Then as [explained by the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#protect-queries-against-sql-injection-attacks), the very purpose of these placeholders is to prevent SQL injections.

Hence you can consider your code safe against SQL injections.

Personally I like to cast my values in the right type as soon as possible, now maybe this is the purpose of `filter_input`, which I don't know about.

```
$asd = (int) filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'TypeM', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$zxc = (int) filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mailFor', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Answer (score -3):

Probably not. You should probably do something like this:

```
$wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE mail_sttng set setting_val=%d
    WHERE setting=1
    ", htmlspecialchars($asd)));
```

And if **setting_val** is not a string field you might want to validate that the right data type is also being passed

Comment: The purpose of the `prepare` method is to handle the data appropriately already. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ Adding an additional “layer” of encoding on top of that is wrong, and using `htmlspecialchars` in relation to database queries, make no sense to begin with.

Comment: "Probably" sounds like you are not sure, so could you at least explain **why** this should be neccessary?